# prettier messes up jsx fragments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prettier, prettier-eslint

```
function App() {
    
      return (
       <>
        <
        Navbar / >
        <
        Users / >
       </>
      );
    }
```

on hitting ctrl+Save this changes to

```
function App() {

  return ( <
    >
    <
    Navbar / >
    <
    Users / >
    <
    />
  );
}
```

when i hover over the fragment it says "JSX fragment has no corresponding closing tag."

i tried installing prettier again ,didn't help

Comment: Maybe this article will help you to solve your problem: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/449

Comment: Did you try using prettier directly from the command line ? Same with eslint --fix ? This would check whether it's a vs code issue vs eslint / prettier

Comment: @Axnyff i used the Vs Code Extension for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the `Prettier plugin` and disable `beautify` plugin or any other code formatter you have pre-installed in the VS code.

This may help you resolve your current issue. This happens due to the fact that both plugins work differently and keeping both enabled refects us with this formate on save.
Disabling beautify and installing the Prettier plugin helps us in achieving the required output.

You can find the Prettier plugin ([here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)).

Answer (score 1):

Solution

i uninstalled other formatter " beautify".
i was hitting "shift+alt+f" for formating the document repeatedly and this popped up on the  bottom right
"there are mutliple formatters . Select a default formatter to continue".
then i chose prettier -code formatter

refer to the article https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/449 mentioned by @Shivanshu Gupta in the comments above

Answer (score -1):

**Short Syntax**

There is a new, shorter syntax you can use for declaring fragments. It looks like empty tags:

```
class Columns extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Link: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax