# JSX has no corresponding closing tag. ts(17014)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite a newbie in react .getting this error Jsx fragment has no corresponding closing tag
here is my code

cart.js

```
import React from "react";

  export default function Cart(){

    return < > Cart < />
}
```

add product.js

```
import react from "react";

    export default function addproduct() {

      return < > addproduct < />

}
```

Comment: Try it without the spaces in between: `<> </>`

Comment: I wonder if your parser does not like the spaces in the fragments.

Comment: tried without the spaces but when i save my work the spaces appear .I'm using vs code

Comment: "when i save my work the spaces appear ... using vs code" That is very strange, and should not happen. Do you have some kind of auto formatting extension active? Also, check what is in your `.editorconfig` file (if there is one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got a solution from [prettier messes up jsx fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663307/prettier-messes-up-jsx-fragments) seems when i saved my work it got messy because i had not installed Prettier plugin .Did so and the problem was solved.

If that does not work for you Save  without formatting to do that use

```
command+shift+p
```

to open the command palette and type "save without" until you see "file:"save without formatting"click it to save without formatting if installing prettier does not work

Answer (score 1):

For your editor to make automatic changes in your code, i think you need to check the `.editorconfig file` and disable any automatic format of the codes.

You could as well install the cool code formatter `Prettier`, it formats your code very nicely ans could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are likely added due to your VS code configuration, as a workaround you can use `React.Fragment` instead of the empty tags like this

```
 <React.Fragment>addproduct</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: when i use React.Fragment  their is an error that JSX element  'React.Fragment' has no corresponding closing tag

Comment: Did you try to copy the code that I posted? can you check if your editor makes any changes to it?

Comment: Yeah it does guess my editor is the problem

Comment: You can try to install the `Prettier` extension for VS code and set it to the default formatter for you file type, maybe this will help.